# Unable to install updates

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 5c running IOS 10.3.3. About 3 days ago I tried to install updates and I keep getting "cannot connect to app store". I tried to log onto my iTunes and Apple Store in my settings, but I keep getting a "Verification Failed. There was an error in connecting to your Apple ID." It also will not allow me to do the 2-step verification for gmail saying "check back soon - there was a problem downloading the latest updates. try again later." I have done a hard reboot numerous times which has not corrected the issue. I don't know what is wrong and how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you able to log into icloud.com using the same Apple ID and password?

Comment: no, it says verification failed. there was an error in connecting to your Apple ID.

Comment: Then you need to contact Apple Support to get the issue with your Apple ID resolved.